# Minimizing the Sum of Square of Distances on a straight line

Tags: algorithm

> A total of n apartment buildings is coming up on a new street. The postal service wants to place a single mailbox on the street. Their objective is to minimize the total square of distances that residents have to walk to collect their mail each day.
>
> Building i has r[i] residents, and is at distance d[i] from the beginning of
>   the street. Devise an algorithm that computes a distance m from the beginning of the street for the mailbox that minimizes the total square of distance, that residents travel to get to the mailbox.

My plan is to sort the building based on the distance from the beginning of the street. Then, find the total number of residents and calculate the median. The mailbox is then placed at the building which corresponds to the median of the residents. Is it the correct way to solve it?

Comment: No.  Take a piece of graph paper and label x and y axes.  Place the mailbox at one end of the street.  Calculate the total (weighted) sum of squared distances the residents will have to walk to the mailbox.  Mark a point on your graph paper at `(0,y(0))`.  Move the mailbox one-tenth of the distance to the other end of the street.  Mark a point on the graph at `(0.1,y(0.1))`.  Repeat all the way to the other end of the street.  You've just drawn a curve a bit like a parabola.  Your task is to find the value for `x` which minimises `y`.

Comment: How about sorting based on the value of `r[i]^2 * d[i]^2` since this is what is targeted to be minimum and then selecting the median of that aray? In short, you want to minimize the **weighted squared distances** it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to minimize:

```
sum(r[i](m-d[i])^2)
```

to solve this, differentiate with respect to m:

```
sum( 2.r[i].(m-d[i]) )
```

to find the minimum, set the derivative to 0:

```
0 = sum( 2.r[i].(m-d[i]) )
m.sum(r[i]) = sum(r[i].d[i])
m = sum(r[i].d[i]) / sum(r[i])
```

i.e. m is the weighted mean of the distances.

(If you wanted to minimize the sum of absolute distance, then the answer would be given by the median instead.)